Power Automate: Teams Workflow Not Working
So, it is my understanding that with the new Workflows app in Teams, I should be able to post a standard "webhook" that worked with Microsoft 365 connectors to a target webhook URL and then it will process that data and post it to a Teams channel.
Workflow looks like this:

HOWEVER, when we post content like this to the workflow:
{
  "attachments": [
    {
      "type": "AdaptiveCard",
      "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
      "version": "1.5",
      "body": [
        {
          "type": "Container",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "New TextBlock",
              "wrap": true,
              "weight": "Bolder",
              "size": "Large"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "ColumnSet",
          "columns": [
            {
              "type": "Column",
              "width": "stretch",
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "Col 1, Row 1:",
                  "wrap": true,
                  "weight": "Bolder"
                },
                {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "Co 2, Row 2:",
                  "wrap": true,
                  "weight": "Bolder"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "Column",
              "width": "stretch",
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "Col 2, Row 1",
                  "wrap": true
                },
                {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "Col 2, Row 2",
                  "wrap": true
                }
                      ]
                  }
              ]
          }
      ]
  }
  ],
  "type":  "message",
}

we get this error reply from the request end:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "TriggerInputSchemaMismatch",
        "message": "The input body for trigger 'manual' of type 'Request' did not match its schema definition. Error details: 'Required properties are missing from object: contentType, content.'."
    }
}

I'm confused as to where to move on this, because this doesn't seem to match any known documented format for using the Workflow app (Power Automate) in Teams to process messages.
So either Microsoft's documentation is not updated, or I'm doing something wrong.
Anyone got any idea what "schema" format I have to apply to the JSON to work properly with the Workflow/Automate app's workflows?

Ensure that the request body includes the required properties contentType and content. Could you please refer the JSON format as stated here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/teams/?tabs=text1%2Cdotnet#microsoft-teams-webhook

@Prasad-MSFT do me a favor and update the core Connectors document links, because all the links currently point to the old way that doesn't require those content items now.  I've updated my stuff accordingly and it worked, but you ALSO need to document that only AdaptiveCards version 1.3 works, 1.5 is not renderable in Teams.  Despite the MSFT documentation saying it supports 1.5.

Thanks for your feedback. We will share this with documentation team to get the document updated. Additionally, please post your solution as 'Answer', so that other developers encountering same problem can resolve their issues following your solution.

So, there are multiple issues at play.
Firstly, Teams workflows in this way only support up to AdaptiveCards 1.3, evidenced by the current New Teams functions.  Despite the documentation saying AdaptiveCards 1.5.  Which means 1.5 cards do not render in a way the Teams desktop apps can use in all cases.  Which means documentation in Microsoft's end is out of date (and I indicated to Prasad to yell at the Documentation teams to update this note.)
Secondly, as Prasad-MSFT said in comments on my question, with the documentation here, this contained the proper format, in that "attachments" items each need their own contentType, contentUrl, and content sections.  This differs from past webhooks which don't refer to this need.  As such, Microsoft has to properly relink all documentation on this and make it actually functional.
Taking all this into account, the adaptive card submit looks like this in the actual body content submitted:
{
  "type": "message",
  "attachments": [
    {
      "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
      "contentUrl": null,
      "content": {
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
        "version": "1.3",
        "body": [
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Test Card",
            "wrap": true,
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "size": "Large"
          },
          {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
              {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": "stretch",
                "items": [
                  {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "Col 1:",
                    "wrap": true,
                    "weight": "Bolder"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": "stretch",
                "items": [
                  {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "Col 2",
                    "wrap": true
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}


The desired JSON card format required has been documented in each webhook documentation pages under 'Important' note.

Also, we tried using the same Adaptive card JSON with version 1.5 and observed that it renders correctly. https://i.sstatic.net/Wxy5EJtw.png

@Prasad-MSFT you and I can communicate externally.  Linked to my profile here is my launchpad.net (Ubuntu) profile.  There is a link there that you can use to email me.  I'd rather have a separate "Things aren't working" discussion via email than here.  Currently, the New Teams application for workplaces shows an error of "unable to display card" for anything over version 1.3 currently.  Your engineers and myself can coordinate externally to here.  Please have someone reach out via the aforementioned mechanism to touch base with me. I'll lead any further discussions on this version issue there
